# jQuery change event code not completed in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

The code below is working ok in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but not in IE (I'm using IE 9). The first three browsers execute all the code, so alert1 and alert2 both are shown. The strange thing is in IE alert1 is shown, but alert2 is not (and also the rest of the code is not executed). What's going on here?

```
    $("#btnUpload").change(function () {
        alert("alert1");
        var data = new FormData();
        alert("alert2");
        data.append("dummybestandsnaam", $("#btnUpload").get(0).files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "FileUploadHandler.ashx?vllid=" + $("#txtVllID").val(),
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            //START
            xhr: function () {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                        percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                        $("#divpb").progressbar({ value: percentComplete });
                    }
                }, false);
                return xhr;
            },
            //EINDE
            beforeSend: function () { $("#divpb").show() },
            error: function (err) { },
            success: function (result) {
                //loze parameter aan url meegeven is noodzakelijk omdat anders de image niet ververst vanwege cache
                var d = new Date();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "get_img_thumb.ashx?vllid=" + $("#txtVllID").val() + "&r=" + d.getTime(),
                    datatype: "image/jpg",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var d2 = new Date();
                        $("#imgUploaded").attr("src", "get_img_thumb.ashx?vllid=" + $("#txtVllID").val() + "&r=" + d2.getTime());
                    }
                });
                //$("#divGelukt").show("slow", function () { });
            },
            complete: function () { $("#divpb").hide() }
        });
    });
```

Snippet HTML

```
<label class="myLabel">
    <input type="file" ID="btnUpload" accept="image/*" />
    <span>Wijzig foto</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Your issue seems obvious, now check support for `FormData`. As a good advice, use your console for debugging purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formdata is not supported by IE9.
Usefull links:

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2
- http://ahedg.es/webkit/formdata.html